# Simple Integral Involving Radicals: Why Does Mathematica Fail?

Tags: integration

I have

$$\int_{d-1}^{3}\textrm{d}x\left(3-x\right)^3 \sqrt{\left(\frac{2(x-1)}{x}\right) \left(x-\left(d-1\right)\right)}$$

but despite this looking like a simple integral involving fractional powers of $x$ with shifts, Mathematica fails, despite restricting $d$ $\in[3,4]$ and $$\left(\frac{2(x-1)}{x}\right) \left(x-\left(d-1\right)\right)>0$$

Can anyone help with the integral? Why is Mathematica failing?

Comment: Does it matter that the the dx comes before the integrand? I've never used mathematica, but that stood out.

Comment: I'm just integrating with respect to $x$ in the usual way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was lucky to trick Mathematica *this time*, by first calculating the value for $d=\pi$ and then replace all instances of $\pi$ by $d$. When plotting the result towards numerical integration it is the same. I don't want to compute this beast by hand, though. And the result is rather long, so I just give the Mathematica commands and attach a figure, see the end.

```
 intpi=Integrate[(3-x)^3 Sqrt[(2(x-1)/x) (x-(Pi-1))], {x,Pi-1,3}]
```

the result is horrible

```
 int[d_]=intpi/.Pi->d
```

The real integral

```
 nint[d_] := NIntegrate[(3-x)^3 Sqrt[(2(x-1)/x) (x-(d-1))], {x, d-1,3}]
```

Comparison (Chop is there to avoid small complex rounding errors)

```
 GraphicsRow[{Plot[nint[d], {d, 3, 4}], Plot[Chop[int[d]], {d, 3, 4}]}]
```

The result is shown below. I'm rather convinced.

[image: plots]

[image]

PS: I don't know if this question fits best here or on Mathematica SE.

Comment: let me just read this....

Comment: thanks for this, but I can't accept it as correct without a simpler formula. Do you know why your answer has a complex part, despite the real integral?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Also, I'm not really familiar with the elliptic integrals occuring. I wish you luck in finding a cleaner result.

Comment: That probably is the simplest, so I'll make this the correct answer. Cheers!