# Approximating ArcCos(x) without Radicals

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, approximation

Take

$$f(x)=2x\arccos\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)$$

and try and find

$$
I(x)=\int_{d-1}^{3}dx f(x) \sqrt{\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}\left(3-x\right)^3
$$

You'll find the result is messy (see [Simple Integral Involving Radicals: Why Does Mathematica Fail?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125420/simple-integral-involving-radicals-why-does-mathematica-fail))

This is caused by the $\arccos$, which in the referenced question has been approximated by a Taylor series about $x=d-1$ truncated to the first term: even in truncated form the integral is all over the place.

Can anyone think of a good approximation to the $\arccos$ function valid when $x\approx d-1$ that doesn't involve radicals, allowing easier integration of $I(x)$?

Comment: The function $I$ should be a function of $d$, not $x$ which is a dummy variable.